# How to write a python program to identify phoone numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I have wirtten some code to identify phone numbers
but it is not working as expected
phone numbers should be format +44-4411109923
Area code such as +44 is optional and - and space before the phone number is also optional.
I have written code below

```
import re
phoneregex = re.compile(r'[+0-9]?(\s|-)\d{10}')
text = input('Enter your text')
print(phoneregex.findall(text))
```

but it is identifying only '-' symbol can anyone tell me where im making mistake ??

I m expecting for some help to understand where im making mistake and learn how to code better.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed your `phoneregex` pattern and created a function that determines whether a string represents a phone number. Here's the code:

```py
import re


def is_phone_number(phone_number: str) -> bool:
    """Determine if string represents a phone number.

    A valid phone number is of one of the following forms:

    - ``"+xx xxxxxxxxxx"``
    - ``"+xx-xxxxxxxxxx"``
    - ``"+xx - xxxxxxxxxx"``
    - ``"+xx xxxxxx-xxxx"``
    - ``"+xx-xxxxxx-xxxx"``
    - ``"+xx - xxxxxx-xxxx"``
    - ``"xxxxxxxxxx"``
    - ``"xxxxxx-xxxx"``

    Where ``"x"`` is a digit. For more details, please refer to the
    examples section.

    Parameters
    ----------
    phone_number : str
        The string to check.

    Returns
    -------
    bool
        ``True`` if string represents a phone number, ``False`` otherwise.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> is_phone_number("+44 - 4411109923")
    True
    >>> is_phone_number("+44-4411109923")
    True
    >>> is_phone_number("4411109923")
    True
    >>> is_phone_number("441110-9923")
    True
    >>> is_phone_number("+44-441110-9923")
    True
    >>> is_phone_number("+44 441110-9923")
    True
    >>> is_phone_number("+44 4411109923")
    True
    >>> is_phone_number("US 4411109923")
    False
    >>> is_phone_number("+44 44111099231010")
    False
    """
    phone_regex = re.compile(
        r'((\+[0-9]{2})(\s|-|\s-\s)|)([0-9]{10}|[0-9]{6}\-[0-9]{4})'
    )
    match = re.match(phone_regex, phone_number)
    return bool(hasattr(match, 'group'))


phone_number = input('Enter your phone number: ')
if is_phone_number(phone_number):
    print(f'{phone_number} is a valid phone number.')
```

### Note

If you wish to maintain your original implementation, you can replace only the `phoneregex` value for the one being used inside `is_phone_number` function, like so:

```py
import re

phoneregex = = re.compile(
    r'((\+[0-9]{2})(\s|-|\s-\s)|)([0-9]{10}|[0-9]{6}\-[0-9]{4})'
)
text = input('Enter your text')
print(phoneregex.findall(text))
```

### Hint

The are many websites that can help you build your regex pattern. I recommend using [regex101](https://regex101.com/) for helping you create the correct pattern. Here's a screenshot of how building the pattern looks like, when using [regex101](https://regex101.com/):

[image]